# Generating strings from a list of characters

Tags: python, generator

I have the following letters:

```
Letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

What I would like is to write a generator function that will create strings that can be formed by taking a combination of any of the letters, preferably in some deterministic order like from smallest to biggest.

So for example if I were to run the generator 20 times I would get

```
 a
 b
 c
 d
 e

aa
ab
ac
ad
ae

ba
bb
bc
bd
be

ca
cb
cc
cd
ce

da
```

How would I write this generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the combinations functions from the itertools library. There's both combinations with replacement and without replacement

```
for item in itertools.combinations(Letters, 2):
    print("".join(item))
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html

Comment: I tried `combinations`, then looked at the rest of the module and found that `permutations` was more suitable for what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generator function:

```
from itertools import *

def wordgen(letters):
    for n in count(1):
        yield from map(''.join, product(letters, repeat=n))
```

Usage:

```
for word in wordgen('abcde'):
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
ba
bb
bc
bd
be
ca
...
```

A self-made alternative without using itertools:

```
def wordgen(letters):
    yield from letters
    for word in wordgen(letters):
        for letter in letters:
            yield word + letter
```

Golf-version (admittedly starts with the empty string):

```
def w(s):yield'';yield from(w+c for w in w(s)for c in s)
```

Comment: Don't clutter the namespace with a ``from module import *``. Either import the individual functions you need, or just use ``import module`` and dot notation.

Comment: @pzp I'm not writing a tutorial on how to import. I'm writing an mcve answer for the question. That said, I'm new here, so if you show me a community guideline saying I should do it differently, then I likely will.

Comment: `yield from`is python 3?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. [looks like it](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html), yes. First time I'm using it, actually. Good exercise :-)

Comment: I'm curious , `map(''.join, product(letters, repeat=n))` generates whole list (stored in RAM) and then each element is passed when is required, or each item in the list is generated in each iteration (this would be the best) ....

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Both `product` and `map` are yielding iterators (hope I got the terminology right). Go ahead and try my code, but start with `count(70)`. Starts printing happily right away, and the whole list certainly wouldn't fit into my RAM.

Comment: @MxyL This should be the answer ..... is very simple :-) ..... in python 2 change `for letter in letters: .... yield letter` instead of `yield from letters`

Comment: @StefanPochmann I apologize. My comment was meant to only be a suggestion, but I guess I phrased it badly. Even though how you import from itertools is not part of the question, it is still widely accepted that it's best not to use ``from module import *``. Not only does doing so clutter the namespace, as I mentioned above, but it also makes your code slightly less readable. If one specifies exactly which functions they are importing, it is clear to the reader where they come from (and this is definitely true with dot notation as well). It's nice to demonstrate good coding practices in answers

Comment: [``map()``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is not an iterator in Python 2.x (as you can see from the docs, it returns a list). If you are looking for an iterator version of it, use [``imap()``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap). If you are using Python 3.x, like @StefanPochmann, then you don't need to worry about this and should just use [``map()``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: @pzp Yes, commanding me to do something was not the nicest phrasing. Anyway. I might not use it in production code, where I agree it could clutter the namespace. But here on SO, I don't want to clutter the screenspace / the actual solution. And I do think my *actual solution* code does show good practices.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product, imap
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
letters += imap(''.join, product(letters, repeat=2))
print letters
```

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd', 'ce', 'da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd', 'de', 'ea', 'eb', 'ec', 'ed', 'ee']

Answer (score 0):

I use a recursive generator function (without itertools)

```
Letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

def my_generator(list, first=""):
  for letter in list:
    yield first + letter
  my_generators = []
  for letter in list:
    my_generators.append(my_generator(list, first + letter))
  i = 0
  while True:
    for j in xrange(len(list)**(i/len(list)+1)):
      yield next(my_generators[i%len(list)])
    i+=1

gen = my_generator(Letters)
[next(gen) for c in xrange(160)]
```

you get

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'ba', 'bb',
'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd', 'ce', 'da', 'db', 'dc',
'dd', 'de', 'ea', 'eb', 'ec', 'ed', 'ee', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad',
'aae', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'acd',
'ace', 'ada', 'adb', 'adc', 'add', 'ade', 'aea', 'aeb', 'aec', 'aed', 
'aee', 'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bad', 'bae', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bbd',
'bbe', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'bcd', 'bce', 'bda', 'bdb', 'bdc', 'bdd',
'bde', 'bea', 'beb', 'bec', 'bed', 'bee', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cad',
'cae', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cbd', 'cbe', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc', 'ccd',
'cce', 'cda', 'cdb', 'cdc', 'cdd', 'cde', 'cea', 'ceb', 'cec', 'ced',
'cee', 'daa', 'dab', 'dac', 'dad', 'dae', 'dba', 'dbb', 'dbc', 'dbd',
'dbe', 'dca', 'dcb', 'dcc', 'dcd', 'dce', 'dda', 'ddb', 'ddc', 'ddd',
'dde', 'dea', 'deb', 'dec', 'ded', 'dee', 'eaa', 'eab', 'eac', 'ead',
'eae', 'eba', 'ebb', 'ebc', 'ebd', 'ebe', 'eca', 'ecb', 'ecc', 'ecd', 
'ece', 'eda', 'edb', 'edc', 'edd', 'ede', 'eea', 'eeb', 'eec', 'eed',
'eee', 'aaaa', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaad', 'aaae']
```

Comment: this code have a problem: i required to use `my_generators` variable and store generators ( > RAM )

Comment: Thanks, you motivated me to write my own generator without using itertools. I added it to my answer.